# How to embed ruby variables in cucumber.feature tests

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have following cucumber test

```
Scenario Outline: 
  Given site <url> is available
  Then I see all all content

Examples:
|url|
|"google.com|
```

In the test case  is dynamic and is generated in ruby code.

Problem:
I want to replace google.com with a ruby variable e.g., <%URL%>. Is that possible to embed ruby code in cucumber tests and evaluate ?

Comment: A comprehensive book : http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not do that on the feature steps. If you need a ruby variable here it means that you are doing something wrong. Check some examples around

[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681249/good-cucumber-examples-in-the-wild)

The features should be clear text so anyone can read, specially non-programmers. so that is why you should now start mixing code with features. The code goes behind, in your step definition.

Comment: thanks, I know what you said but I am just curious if there is a such way

Answer (score 0):

You can `eval` this string it if you trust code in this feature file. But it may be a bad idea for the reasons outlined by @SnakeSanders.