# Laravel unit tests in the wild

Tags: laravel-4, phpunit

Where would be a good place to find Laravel unit tests in the wild? Similar to this: [Good Cucumber examples in the wild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681249/good-cucumber-examples-in-the-wild)
but for laravel. I know there are lots of examples out there but I’m looking for real tests based on a real project.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at Laravel's own test suite, which is quite extensive and is based on PHPUnit. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/tests.